# Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration]

Tags: java, spring, xsd, hibernate-validator

I am using spring 3, hibernate validator 4. My unit test is running fine. But i am getting this(see below) for my functional test, have i miss out some dependencies?

Dependencies i had added for hibernate validator:

1. validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
2. hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA.jar

Here's my the content of validation.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<validation-config xmlns="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration
    http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration/validation-configuration-1.0.xsd">

    <default-provider>org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator</default-provider>
    <message-interpolator>org.hibernate.validator.engine.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator</message-interpolator>
    <traversable-resolver>org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver</traversable-resolver>
    <constraint-validator-factory>org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConstraintValidatorFactoryImpl</constraint-validator-factory>
    <!-- <configuration:constraint-mapping>constraints-user.xml</configuration:constraint-mapping> -->

</validation-config>
```

The error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration]
Offending resource: class path resource [hibernate/validation.xml]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1332)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:142)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:93)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:187)
    ... 57 more
```

I have search around and i found no solution =(. Any idea? thank you~!

Answer (score 1):

`validation.xml` is not a Spring config file, you shouldn't try to load it with Spring.